# Как переподписать apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

На телефоне через Android Studio было установлено приложение. Папка с самим проектом утеряна, но с телефона вытащил apk, которое подписано debug ключом. Открыл apk через Android Studio, при попытке Build -> Generate Signed APK ничего не делает и пишет в Event Log "All files are up-to-date". Можно ли как-то (не только через Android Studio) переподписать приложение, чтобы его можно было установить на любое устройство?

На данный момент при подключении другого устройства к студии приложение установить можно, но оно опять же подписано дебажным ключом. Есть идея заменить в файлах Android Studio файл "debug.keystore" на какой-нибудь другой с релизным ключом, возможно ли её реализовать?

Comment: Посмотрите решения из этого [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913207/resign-apk-with-different-keystore)